# Window.open not working in another pop up window

Tags: php, javascript, html, window.open

I have a popup window 'X' generated using javascript `window.open()`. When I try to open another child window 'Y' from the pop-up window 'X', i have getting a pop up window 'Y' and also the url of the 'X' reloading to the orignial browser window. Can any one please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I try with this one and it worked for me:

```
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<button class='hi' onclick='window.open()'> hi!</button>");
myWindow.focus();
}
<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be you have not `return false` when opening other child window Y from the pop up X window. So your browser is reloading. Try this if still not work post your script if possible!

Comment: sure...i will try this and let you know the result.

Comment: ofcouse! but if it does not work place your code i will try to debug my best

Comment: I got the solution. My problem was  that I declared href="#" inside anchor. That was causing the page reloading in parent window. Thanks for your help though. Cheers:)